# Boost problems when compiling Point Cloud Library

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, point-cloud-library

I am trying to compile the Point Cloud Library from source on OSX 10.6.8, and I keep running up against the same error with the Boost libraries:

```
! make
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libpcl_common.dylib
Undefined symbols:
  "boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept()", referenced from:
  boost::thread::thread<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, 

pcl::TimeTrigger>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<pcl::TimeTrigger*> > > >(boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, pcl::TimeTrigger>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<pcl::TimeTrigger*> > >, boost::disable_if_c<boost::thread_detail::is_convertible<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, pcl::TimeTrigger>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<pcl::TimeTrigger*> > >&, boost::detail::thread_move_t<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, pcl::TimeTrigger>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<pcl::TimeTrigger*> > > > >::value, boost::thread::dummy*>::type)in time_trigger.cpp.o
  "boost::thread::join_noexcept()", referenced from:
      pcl::TimeTrigger::~TimeTrigger()in time_trigger.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libpcl_common.1.7.0.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have looked through the CMake options, and <strike>none of them seem to reference the Boost library</strike> with advanced settings activated, I find that my boost library files are located in `/usr/lib/`; e.g. `/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.dylib`:

[image]

What can I do to solve this problem? And what can I do in the future to help prevent similar problems occurring again?

---

**UPDATE** I have rebuilt and compiled Boost from scratch, and am still getting the same error. This seems very odd, as Boost is compiled from scratch and PCL is too. The only thing which could be of note is in the CMake output, I get this strange conflicting message:

```
-- checking for module 'eigen3'
--   package 'eigen3' not found
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/local/include/eigen3)
```

Comment: It's possible you installed boost without building the boost libraries.  A lot of boost is useable via header files only, but some features require libraries which need to be explicitly built.  Look for libboost_* libraries (e.g. libboost_thread) in your boost install directory to see if they exist.

Comment: Ok thanks, in `/usr/lib` I have among other things `libboost_thread-mt.a` and `libboost_thread-mt.dylib`. The `dylib` file is referenced in the CMake (see edited question). I am now reinstalling Boost to see if this improves things.

Comment: Just a heads-up: don't use the [PCL] tag. It is not related to the Point Cloud Library.

Comment: AFAIK that error has nothing to do with Eigen. One thing you can do is running make in verbose mode to see where the linker is looking for your libraries: At shell prompt write: VERBOSE=1 make

Answer (score 0):

Is this an "older version of boost" problem?

Perhaps the linker is looking for functions that only exist in a newer version of boost than the one you have built and installed.

Double check what version of boost is recommended by the Point Cloud Library, and what version of boost you have.