# Broken CMake and GCC under OS X

Tags: c, gcc, cmake

When running `configure` in `cmake-gui` on my OS X platform, I get the following error occurring:

```
The C compiler identification is GNU
The CXX compiler identification is GNU
Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-4.0
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-4.0 -- broken
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake 2.8-2.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (MESSAGE):
  The C compiler "/usr/bin/gcc-4.0" is not able to compile a simple test
  program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: /Users/bill/Desktop/cmake_test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

  Run Build Command:/opt/local/bin/gmake "cmTryCompileExec/fast"

  /opt/local/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/build

  gmake[1]: Entering directory
  `/Users/bill/Desktop/cmake_test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  "/Applications/CMake 2.8-2.app/Contents/bin/cmake" -E cmake_progress_report
  /Users/bill/Desktop/cmake_test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1

  Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

  /usr/bin/gcc-4.0 -isysroot -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c
  /Users/bill/Desktop/cmake_test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

  i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.0.1:
  CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o: No such file or
  directory

    <snip>
```

From looking at forums, etc. on the Internet, I have established that this could be to do with my PATH variable. Here is my PATH variable for analysis:

```
! echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
```

This path variable has recently changed when I configured Python, and I think that the GCC problems must have sprung up at the same sort of time. What could be wrong with my system installation for this to be occurring?

---

Some more details. The build program specified by `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` is `/opt/local/bin/gmake`.

I have also discovered that these errors are only thrown when running `Configure` in `cmake-gui`. On the command line (running `cmake ..` from a build folder), the configuration completes fine:

```
! cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.0.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.2.1
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-4.0 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

However, compilation is not always successful when using some libraries - see for example [this question I have asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449887/boost-problems-when-compiling-point-cloud-library). I therefore think something might still be going wrong in the `cmake` process.

Comment: The output of the failed compile test is possibly the most useful piece of information in that log.

Comment: Thanks, I have included the full CMake output. It looks like maybe the  creation of the object files is not working correctly?

Comment: Then check your installation for binutils

Comment: Ok I have now reinstalled binutils on my system from scratch and I get the same issue. Am unsure how to proceed so have offered a bounty to get some more attention for this issue.

Comment: That's because it tries to use `/opt/local/bin/gmake`. Where Make is installed? And what generator do you specify to CMake? Update your question.

Comment: I'll ask again: _what **generator** do you specify?_ Please, when you answer, address the answer to me, so that I'm notified.

Comment: What OSX and XCode version is this ? And what does /usr/bin/gcc-4.0 -isysroot -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /Users/bill/Desktop/cmake_test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c actually give ?

Comment: Well I don't specify a ***generator***. One isn't listed in the options under `ccmake`. So it is quite hard for me to answer that question. In `cmake-gui` I found that the current generator is stated as `Unix Makefiles`, so maybe that is being used.

Comment: That's impossible, when you click `Configure` it asks you for the **generator**.

Comment: It's fairly clear that the generator chosen by `cmake` is `"/usr/bin/gcc-4.0"`. Please answer the question asked by @IgmarPalsenberg so that we can help you. Just trust us... Some of us have had very similar problems on very similar systems (eg. the same error message on a jailbroken iPod). I'm almost certain you'll get a linker error (eg. `ld: undefined reference ...`) indicating that you need to install glibc (or some wrapper to wrap the standard C library in the objective-C framework).

Comment: Hmmm.. After I get the errors, `CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec.dir` does not exist. Some other similar ones did, but I couldn't get anything to compile using the suggested `/usr/bin/gcc-4.0` command. I am not asked for a generator version. This is using OSX 10.6.8 and XCode version 3.2.6. I think my best bet is to make the upgrade to Mountain Lion and see if it fixes any problems I have. Thanks for everyones help on this problem.

Comment: The versions of C compiler and CXX compiler are different according to the log (4.0 and 4.2). This indicates some issues with the toolchain set-up. Updating OS and toolchain in general and bringing them in sync will certainly help.

Comment: Consider that the GCC version you are using, 4.0, is 8 years old (2005).  Check the libraries you are using are compatible with that version. Consider upgrading your compiler, either to GCC 4.8 or to Clang 3.3.

Comment: @IgmarPalsenberg - The machine must be earlier than the last OS X 10.5. I have a PowerMac I use for testing, and it runs OS X 10.5 and provides GCC 4.1 as the default compiler. Just guessing, but OP is running OS X 10.4. If you have an SSH key I can give you an account on the PowerMac with the ancient tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some observations about your question, which may lead you to a solution...

You are using CMake 2.8.2, which is fairly old, as far as CMake versions go. Try with 2.8.11 or a release candidate of the upcoming 2.8.12 to see if the problem still exists. If nothing else, perhaps you'll get a better error message.

See this question and answer and its links to see about the various ways of guaranteeing consistent `PATH` values between command line environments and GUI applications launched via other means on the Mac: *[How do I set the global PATH environment variable on OS X?](https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-do-i-set-the-global-path-environment-variable-on-os-x/277034#277034)*

The CMake GUI does not necessarily inherit the same PATH value as you see in your Terminal, unless you launch it from the Terminal with an open command.

Two other things pop out at me here: GCC 4.0 is the C compiler, but g++ 4.2 is the C++ compiler. Why are those different?

Also, `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` points to `/opt/local/bin/gmake`. Is that true in both of your build trees? (The command line one and the GUI one?) It seems curious to me that CMake would pick up the C and C++ compilers from `/usr/bin`, but gmake from `/opt/local/bin`...

Is your command line environment carefully set up to use exactly these tools from these paths? Or is this also unexpected to you?

You don't mention what version of the Xcode tools you are using at all. Perhaps adding that to your question will help a better answer pop into someone's brain.

One last observation: you have a lot of stuff in your PATH. Minimizing the PATH value you use in your build environments will go a long way to helping you avoid problems like this. I heartily recommend stripping that down to the bare minimum you need, at least for a software building environment.

Sorry for the non-answer answer, but this much commentary seemed a bit excessive for a Stack Overflow comment... :-)

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! You have added a lot of detail and knowledge. I think ultimately my system was quite broken, and I have done a complete system reinstall and this has helped straighten things out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this issue, and I have fixed it by setting the correct `CXXFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS`. I think you should also check it.

One simple solution would be:

`CPPFLAGS := $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS := $(CXXFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)`

Or you should check whether your `PATH` is correct. You should be able to find the `CXX` compiler and C compiler in your current shell.